# Checking database with Recursive Function

Tags: php, recursion

i'm trying to do a recursive function. It's a simple id creation and checking the id inside the database. If the id is already created, then it should run the function back to create a new id and do the checking again. Below is the code.

```
public function session_order(){
    $sr_function = new sr_function();
    $session_no = (rand(0,2));
    //i have set the order_id in the db as '1'//

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(order_id) as order_count 
    FROM src_order WHERE order_id = '".$session_no."'";

    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    if ($row['order_count'] == 1){
        $this->session_order();
    } 

    return $session_no;
}
```

how ever, when $row['order_count'] == 1, the function did not run the session_order() back to create another session no. Thank you

Comment: You should return it: `return $this->session_order();`. However.. I don't recommend this kind of verification. One of the problems is that you are using the rand() function with a very small range of numbers. Using it may return you the same number 20 times for example.. This means 20 queries from the same user

Comment: The session_no created in the inner call to the function will never get used. The function calls use separate scopes, the variables are separate.

Comment: the rand no is actually 7 digits, i just put it very small just to test the function

Answer (score 0):

When you generate a successful ID, you need to pass it back up the call stack.

```
if ($row['order_count'] == 1){
    $session_no = $this->session_order();
}
```

Why are you doing this with recursion?  A simple iterative loop seems more reasonable.  For one thing, the current implementation repeats the DB query for every ID creation.  Isn't the query result supposed to be the same every time?  Or are you altering the ID list in parallel?